# ofy() appengine Date search query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I want to search a list of employee between two dates ie. 1 jan 2014 to 31 Dec 2014 using GAE ofy(objectify) for a branch.How do I do that?

```
ulist=ofy().load().type(Employee.class).filter("branch", branch).filter("date >=", fromdate).filter("date <=", toDate).list();
```

There are 2 fields 
-Branch is auto generated field.
-For date I have taken 2 Datebox, fromDate and toDate and using those 2 date I have to query on date field.

Above query written is not working & not giving results when searched between date. However if same date is entered in both from date & todate then its working.

Is there any isssue with my logic or is there any other method which I can use to find out employees of branch joined between two dates?

Comment: Do you have an index [configured](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes) in your `datastore-indexes.xml`? _"Queries with one or more inequality filters on a property and one or more equality filters on other properties"_

Comment: No,I didn't configured anything in datastore-indexes.xml.

Comment: Can You tell me How do I configure that file.

Comment: The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig) should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: I will post it as an answer. If it helps you please accept it so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify a custom index to support this query as it combines multiple filters on different properties.

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes):

> Other forms of query require their indexes to be specified in the index configuration file, including:
>
> ...
>
> Queries with one or more inequality filters on a property and one or more equality filters on other properties
>
> ...

Your query has an equality filter (on `branch`) with two inequality (on `date`) filters.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig) tells you all you need to know about configuring your custom indexes.

Comment: <datastore-index kind="Employee" ancestor="false" source="manual">  
        <property name="branch" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="date" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>

Comment: I have configure my index like above shown and it works for me.

Comment: In my another query. I used status IN Operator and one inequality filter ie. date <= and one equality filter ie. on Id .

Comment: and for these i have configure my datastore index like as follows     ::    <datastore-index kind="PurchaseOrder" ancestor="false" source="manual">  
        <property name="companyId" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="creationDate" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="status" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
    
    <datastore-index kind="PurchaseOrder" ancestor="false" source="manual">  
        <property name="creationDate" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="status" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>